# How to change alert function to bootstrap modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I wanted to change the following function to bs modal or any other fancy dialogue box.

```
if (Form::mailer($email, $fname, $lname)) {
    echo
        '<script >
    alert("Thank you for registration.");
    window.location = "../test.php"; <
    /script>';
} else {
    echo ' <
        script >
        alert("Error, please try submitting again. Error code 1");
    window.history.back(); <
    /script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace alert with BoostrapDialog:

Need to add these bootstrap CDN first

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js
```

And then replace the alert method with show method of BootstrapDialog

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: 'Thank you for registration.'
});
```

For detail, please refer http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/